# Java - ArrayList<E> Parameter in function

Tags: java

I wanted to use a function that used a arraylist for multiple types of arraylists, but I don't know how to do that.

```
ArrayList<TextView> List2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<View> List1 = new ArrayList<>();

ChangeTextSize(List1);
ChangeTextSize(List2);

public void ChangeTextSize(ArrayList List){
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++){
            List.get(i).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
   }
}
```

-Edit: The function is meant for any view. I'm now aware that setTextSize isn't allowed for view.

Comment: Since `View` doesn't have a `setTextSize` method, it wouldn't make sense. However, if you change the method call to `public void ChangeTextSize(ArrayList<TextView> List){` you'd be able to pass `List1` with less issues

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the text size using the function `setTextSize` the object which you call the function on has to be a `TextView` because that object has the [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). A `View` doesn't have the function `setTextSize` so that won't work.

But if you have a function that both `TextView` and `View` have; for example `setBackgroundColor` you can do it like this:

```
public void changeBackgroundColor(ArrayList<? extends View> list) {
  for (View v: list) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
  }
}
```

So basically you give your `list` argument a generic; meaning in this case: "all the element in the list should be a view or sub-class thereof". So the methods you can call on the element from this list are all methods available in the `View` class.

But if you want to change text-sizes your function needs to accept a list of `TextView` (or sub-classes thereof), like this:

```
public void changeTextSize(ArrayList<? extends TextView> list) {
  for (TextView tv: list) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this Android?

You can use a wild card to allow a range of type-parameters.  Something like:

```
public void ChangeTextSize(ArrayList<? extends TextView> list){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            list.get(i).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
   }
}
```

But I don't see that `View` has a method `setTextSize` so obviously that type can't be used here.